# News article page preview before save the page?

Tags: page-layout

I am using sp 2013. I would like to build a custom pagelayout with some fields like title, description, picture etc.

I would like to make it possible in the edit form that is a button preview. When the user press on the preview button he will see a preview of the news article page. After he press on the OK button it will be saved.

How can I do something like this?

Also development solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to me seems like using versioning. If you enable major minor/versioning on the library, the users can add thier info, save the page, then view it. If they are happy with it, they publish it as a major version. Check in/out could be used in conjunction with version if there will be a lot of authors.

Comment: are there also other solutions? what about the logic which is used in the design manager or in the theme settings page? There it is possible to see a preview.